# How to load SCROM 2004 with cmi.location(user's last location)

Tags: javascript, laravel, scorm2004

I have integrated `https://github.com/gabrieldoty/simplify-scorm` to show the SCROM file content and it's working fine.
The system displays SCORM courses effectively, but it doesn't retain user progress and input data. Our progress data is stored externally, and we need to load this JSON data into the SCORM content during page loading. This project is based on SCORM 2004, aiming to synchronize and save user progress seamlessly within the course materials.

here is the code sample

```
function setupScormApi() { 
                    API_1484_11.Initialize = Initialize;
                    API_1484_11.Commit = Commit;
                    API_1484_11.Terminate = Terminate;
                    API_1484_11.GetValue = GetValue;
                    API_1484_11.SetValue = SetValue;
                    API_1484_11.GetErrorString = GetErrorString;
                    API_1484_11.GetDiagnostic = GetDiagnostic;
                    API_1484_11.GetLastError = GetLastError;
                    API_1484_11.loadFromJSON = loadFromJSON; 
                }
```

Comment: This code sample isn't real helpful in fact.   You've set those SCORM Api endpoints, but have you implemented the backend of GetValue() and SetValue() to write the data to your LMS?